# predicateWithFormat NSMutableArray Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an error with predicateWithFormat causing a crash in my app.

The problematic code is:

```
@implementation SecondViewController
{
NSArray *searchResults;
}

@synthesize jsonConnection, bakeryProductArray, bakeryTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self retrieveData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITableView DataSource

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];
}
else {
return [bakeryProductArray count];

}
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else {
foodProducts *currentProduct = [bakeryProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = currentProduct.productName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentProduct.productName;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

return cell;

}

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (bakeryTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"bakeryDetails" sender: self];
}

    detailedViewController *productinfo = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bakeryDetails"];
    //Retrieve current user array
    foodProducts *currentProduct2 = [bakeryProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    productinfo.productName = currentProduct2.productName;
    productinfo.productImage = currentProduct2.productImgUrl;
    productinfo.productDescription = currentProduct2.productDescription;
    productinfo.productPrice = currentProduct2.productPrice;
    productinfo.productQuantity = currentProduct2.productquantity;
    productinfo.productAllergy = currentProduct2.productAllergy;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:productinfo animated:YES];
    [bakeryTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}


//Becareful here as wrong predicateWithFormat can crash app on keying in search 
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString * testString,    NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ([searchText compare:testString options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame);
}];

searchResults = [bakeryProductArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}


#pragma mark - methods

-(void) retrieveData
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataUrl];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

jsonConnection = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
bakeryProductArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < jsonConnection.count; i++)
{
    NSString *pID = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *pName = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *pImageUrl = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ImageUrl"];
    NSString *pDescription = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Description"];
    NSString *pQuantity = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Quantity"];
    NSString *pPrice = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Price"];
    NSString *pAllergy = [[jsonConnection objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Allergy"];

    foodProducts *myProducts = [[foodProducts alloc]initWithproductID:pID andproductName:pName andproductImgUrl:pImageUrl andproductDescription:pDescription andproductquantity:pQuantity andproductPrice:pPrice andproductAllergy:pAllergy];


    [bakeryProductArray addObject:myProducts];
}


[self.bakeryTableView reloadData];

}
```

FoodProduct class

```
@implementation foodProducts
@synthesize productID, productName, productImgUrl, productquantity,productDescription, productPrice, productAllergy;

-(id) initWithproductID:(NSString *)uproductID andproductName:(NSString *)uproductName andproductImgUrl:(NSString *)uproductImage andproductDescription:(NSString *)uproductDescription andproductquantity:(NSString *)uproductquantity andproductPrice:(NSString *)uproductPrice andproductAllergy:(NSString *)uproductAllergy
{
self = [super init];
if  (self)
{
    productID = uproductID;
    productName = uproductName;
    productImgUrl = uproductImage;
    productquantity = uproductquantity;
    productDescription = uproductDescription;
    productPrice = uproductPrice;
    productAllergy = uproductAllergy;

}
return self;
}
```

The array which is being fed into the NSPredicate is `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *bakeryProductArray;`

Error says: Can't use in/contains operator with collection

Any ideas, on whats going wrong?

Comment: What does the array contain, just strings? The error is quite clear on what's wrong.

Comment: The array carries NSStrings. (I am not a pro programmer so quite clear means nothing to me).

Comment: Could it be that bakeryProductArray is not an array of strings but an array of *objects* that have a string property? - Can you show the *complete* error message?

Comment: updated the questions code section :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array does not contain *strings*, but custom `foodProducts` objects.

To filter the objects by "product name", you would use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
```

*ADDED:* There is another error in your code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

cannot work because the right-hand side does not return a string. It should be

```
foodProducts *currentProduct = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = currentProduct.productName;
```

Comment: Error - this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key text.

Comment: @Evilelement: "text" was just an *example*. You have to use one of the properties of `foodProducts`, for example "productName". - I have updated the answer according to your updated question.

Comment: Bounces, back with this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key item. Still very much a noob. Sorry

Comment: @Evilelement: There is no key "item" in my answer. Please show exactly what you tried and the *complete* error message. Otherwise it is very difficult to help :-)

Comment: foodProducts *searchObject;
    
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"searchObject.productName contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText]; Still very much a noob :(

Comment: @Evilelement: Where does `searchObject` come from?? Can you try the predicate exactly as I suggested and check if that works?

Comment: searchObject was created by me a few minutes ago. I have deleted it not and tested your code and recieved reason: '-[foodProducts isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance :(

Comment: @Evilelement: Did you exactly use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];` ?

Comment: @Evilelement: Does it still crash in `filterContentForSearchText`? Can you show the current code of that method in your question?

Comment: I updated the question above to show the whole implantation file for NSPredict and the implementation for the foodProducts.:D

Comment: @Evilelement: What I meant is: Can you show the `filterContentForSearchText` method using the code from my answer?

Comment: searchResults = [bakeryProductArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]; :)

Comment: @Evilelement: I don't see that code in your updated question, so I cannot verify the *complete* method. It *should* work. - But I have found another problem in your code, see the updated answer.

Comment: Congratulations Martin R and Anup. "cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" was the key to solving the puzzle. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

> NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.productName contains[cd] %@", searchText];
>
> NSArray *searchResults = [self.bakeryProductArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
>
> NSLog(@"%@",searchResults);

If above doesn't work can you show your foodProduct class (model).

Ideally you should use like[cd] instead of contains[cd].

Refer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html
1 CONTAINS
The left-hand expression contains the right-hand expression.

2 LIKE
The left hand expression equals the right-hand expression: ? and * are allowed as wildcard characters, where ? matches 1 character and * matches 0 or more characters.

Comment: It doesn't crash :D But.... it doesn't display any results :( Console reads per character 2013-07-09 21:45:53.737 Jackies[5537:c07] (
    "<foodProducts: 0x9273810>"

Comment: Did you try self.productName, it does not matter though. @Martin and I are basically suggesting the same thing. I am keeping an eye on your conversation with him. Will post if find anything.

Comment: So it is printing one object it seems. Do this also     NSLog(@"Filtered Food Product Count --> %d",[searchResults count]);

Comment: As a suggestion , use NSLog to figure out whats happening. Use Breakpoints. And always add **a exception break point ** (google how to add), that helps you to narrow down your search by a lot. Thanks